# Turn pandas multi index into index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a multiindex. I want to turn this:

```
0    0             black
1    0             brown
2    0             beige
4    0             green
5    0        gris clair
6    0      forest green
7    0               tan
8    0          burgandy
     1             black
9    0         off white
10   0            silver
11   0              pink
```

Into this:

```
0                 black
1                 brown
2                 beige
4                 green
5            gris clair
6          forest green
7                   tan
8              burgandy
9                 black
10             off white
11               silver
12                 pink
```

Not much more to say, though SO says I have written too much code in this post so here I am typing more words.

Comment: `df.reset_index(drop=True)`

Comment: @ayhan, uh did you read the questions? They arent the same at all. The answers are the same, but that is not what you flagged.